# I am developing a Outlook plugin for Outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I am developing a Outlook plugin. For Outlook 2007,2010 and 2013 it's working fine in 2010 and 13 but not showing any tab in 2007. It is installing properly, I also checked in Addins it is in active mode also but it not showing any tab or button of that ADDIN.

Please tell me the proper way to do that.

Comment: Can you share more details of the Addin you are developing ? Whether it is COM addin or VSTO addin? Whether you are using Ribbon visual designer or Ribbon XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure that you don't get any UI errors in Outlook. See [How to: Show Add-in User Interface Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

The Explorer windows in Outlook 2007 don't use the Ribbon UI, only inspectors. So, you need to use command bars for customizing the Explorer windows.

Anyway, what markup did you use for the custom UI? What namespace is used in the markup?